# mySQL - usando SUM()

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando somar o valor total de um pedido com mais de 1 produto incluido com valores unitários diferentes.

segue tb_pedido:

```
id_pedido    | id_produto    | valor_unit | qtd  
-------1-----|-------3-------|----10.00---|--2--  
-------1-----|-------5-------|-----9.00---|--6--
```

meu select:

```
   select pedido.id_produto, sum(pedido.qtd),
   ((select sum(valor_unit) from tb_pedido where id_produto = 
   pedido.id_produto) * pedido.qtd) 
   from tb_pedido pedido 
   where id_pedido = 1
```

o resultado deveria ser **74.00**, mas todos os `select` que faço o resultado é (10.00 * 8 = 80.00) ou (9.00 * 8 = 72.00).

o `select` pega 1 dos dois *valor_unit* e multiplica pela somatório da *qtd*

Comment: Você quer o valor total do pedido? Seu select não deve funcionar. Tem um erro de sintaxe. O que exatamente você que fazer?

Comment: jura, qual erro ? sim, quero valor total do pedido.

Comment: O mysql (de forma bizarra) não dispara um erro, mas uma consulta com campos e agregadores (sum, max, count, etc.) exige um group by. No MySQL ele retorna somente à primeira linha. Mas conceitualmente está errado. Veja no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef1b3b/2). Eu tirei o where mas somente a primeira linha foi retonada (pedido 1, produto 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode agrupar por pedido e somar a multiplicação, assim:

```
select id_pedido,
       sum(valor_unit*qtd) as total
  from tb_pedido
 group by id_pedido
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2b6aa/2)

Comment: Funcionou perfeito ! Simples demais, mas eu não estava enxengando.
obrigado.